# How do direct links to tabs (made with JS) using #anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have site with some info-tabs based on [a template](http://www.2scopedesign.co.uk/themes/guardian/#convey). Tabs have some anchors `example.com/#convey`, but when I try to use direct link to some tab using `#anchor` - nothing happens, because the tabs are using JS.

JS:

```
 /* fading the content in using a sub-menu */
    $('.content-fade-menu a').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var target = $('.content-fade').find(href);
        $('.content-fade-menu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.content-fade .content-fade-panel').hide();
        $(target).fadeIn('fast');
        return false;
    });
```

HTML of menu:

```
<ul class="sub-menu content-fade-menu">
<li><a href="#pi" class="">Personal Injury</a></li>
<li><a href="#employment" class="active">Employment</a></li>
</ul>
```

HTML of one non-active tab and one active tab:

```
<div class="content-fade">
<div class="content-fade-panel" id="pi" style="display: none;">
Non-active tab
</div> 
<div class="content-fade-panel" id="employment" style="display: block;">
Active tab
</div> 
</div>
```

What do I need to do, to make links, like `example.com/#anchor`, work?

Comment: Theoretically, I understand, that script must analyse url for #anchor, and if it exists, than recognize it like "href" and make "click" action automatically. But how to code it - it's a problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer.

```
//Take #anchor from url and find right block
    var loc = window.location.hash;
    if (loc != "") {
    var href = loc;
    var target = $('.content-fade').find(href);

//Unactivate first tab
    $('.content-fade-menu a').removeClass('active');

//Activate right tab
    $('.content-fade-menu a[href="'+href  +'"]').addClass('active');
    $('.content-fade .content-fade-panel').hide();
    $(target).fadeIn('fast');

//Scroll to the h3 of the activated block
     var zagolovok = $(target).find('h3');
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(zagolovok).offset().top}, 300);
    }
```

That's all.